# Условие и действие javascript что div прокручен на 10 px;

Tags: javascript

К концу рабочего дня мозг offline) Задача простая и следующая, как сложить следующую схему в js. Есть родительский div со скроллом, внутри этого div'a еще 2 div'a, один из которых нужно зафиксировать если родительский div был прокручен на 10 px.

Мне нужно только условие:

```
if(условие)
{
действие
}
```

Громадная благодарность за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.onmousewheel = function(){
  if(this.scrollTop >=10px){
    this.children(div1).style.position = 'fixed';
  }
}
```

Как-то так. Это псевдокод, максимально приближенный к JS. Если надо - напишу на JS. Кстати, на чистом или можно с jquery?

Comment: На чистом. у меня свои замуты как без Jquery реализовать работу обращения к DOM элементам типа $('#div).click(function(){ }); и подобные. И на этом спасибо, суть работы возможного скрита я понял.